# fopen to append should also try write?

Tags: c++, c, append, fopen

According to the FAQ at http://www.decompile.com/cpp/faq/fopen_write_append.htm fopen does not always work and should be tried twice to use with log files.

According to the C standard (1990 version) fopen does work when you ask it to append, and the second statement should never have any effect.

I'd like to remove such workarounds from our code base but I'd like to know for sure that there is no commonly available fopen that is malfunctioning, as the first link claims. Does anybody know of any and is such a workaround a normal thing?

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Clang, MSVC, GCC and a few variants.

Comment: Interesting, never faced such an issue in gcc or g++ and I just tried it out without problems (files were created with `"a+"` option no problem). Keep in mind this was written a long time ago, maybe it was an issue that was fixed. Since you are using c++, have you considered `ofstream`?

Comment: I've personally never noticed this issue.  `FILE* f = fopen("test.app", "a+");` creates a file just fine using Visual Studio 2013.  That article is from 2005.

Comment: Me too. I have never seen any problem of using fopen for appending.